# How can I make the text area empty after I click the submit button?

Tags: reactjs

**How can I make the text area empty after I click the submit button??**
Im trying to create a simple form submit in react. Can you please tell me how can i make the text area empty after I click the Submit button. This is my problem.

This is my App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Textarea from "./Textarea";
import Button from "./Button";

export class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state =  {

      Tinput: '',
      // Ninput:'',
      submit: ''
    }
  }
  
  changeHandle = (event) => {
   this.setState({
     Tinput: event.target.value
   })
  }

  submitHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      submit: this.state.Tinput
    })
  }

  resetHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {submit: ''}
    )
  }

  // handleKeypress = (event) => {
  //   if (event.keyCode === 'Enter') {
  //     this.submitHandle();
  //   }
  // }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Textarea changeHandle={this.changeHandle} change={this.state.Tinput}/>
          <Button action={this.submitHandle} name="submit"/>
          <Button action={this.resetHandle} name="Reset" />
        </div>
        <p>{this.state.submit}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

This is my Textarea.js code:

```
import React from 'react'
 const Textarea = (props) => {
     return (
         <div>
            <textarea
            type="text"
            onChange={props.changeHandle}
            // onKeyPress={this.handleKeypress}
            value={props.change}
            className="form-control"
            id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
            placeholder='write something here'
          />
         </div>

     );
 }

 export default Textarea;
```

This is my button.js code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={props.action}>{props.name}</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it as empty in submit function

```
 submitHandle = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          submit: this.state.Tinput,
          Tinput:""
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  submitHandle = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      submit: this.state.Tinput,
      Tinput: '',
    })
  }
```